# Rounding integers in python

Tags: python, list, rounding

My code below is displaying the labels with padding so it looks like a table. But I would like to please know the most efficient way to round the integers which display to 2 decimals.

Can I use `{%:.2f}`???

```
labels = ['','Count:', 'Mean:', 'Median:', 'Minimum:', 'Maximum:', 'Std Dev:']

for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    display_with_padding(label)


    j = 0
    while j < len(data):
        display_with_padding(data[j][i + 0]) #add decimal rounding here
        j += 1
```

Comment: Integers don't have decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rounding floats (not integers) use the builtin `round`:

```
round(float_number, decimal_places)
```

For only string representation you can use (for example):

```
"{:.2f}".format(float_number)
```